# Splash screen prevent from hiding after ejecting expo

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, react-native, expo

Recently I have ejected my project from expo to dare and do all the necessary things like `pod install` and all.

When I run my project Its runs fine but as soon as I click on any modal or any other button its don't show any error logs and shows Splashscreen and it's not hiding the code which should be executed in the use effect is not excuting. Sometimes it's said.

`'SplashScreen.show' has already been called for given view controller.`

It works well on the real device but the splash screen not hiding on the simulator.

I am stuck in for the last 3 days and do all the necessary things. Check almost all the questions on StackOverflow regarding this.

I have also try below code but it doesn't work.

```
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('A');
        setTimeout(async () => {
            console.log('B');
            await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
        }, 10000);
    }, []);

    useEffect(async () => {
        await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }, []);
```

I have tried almost everything and all the things were working perfectly before ejecting;

Comment: Hello, have you tried to prevent the auto hiding like in this [example](https://github.com/expo/examples/blob/master/with-splash-screen/App.js) ?

Also, I recommend you to stay with Expo and simply use the custom dev client who allows you to use native dependencies.

Comment: @adscud I really wanted to use expo but I have to integrate in-app purchase as the client wants it, so I have to do this. I have expo backup too. Check your link thanks.

Comment: No luck by the way thanks @adscud